# hide() and on() doesn't work on internet explorer (IE)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, internet-explorer

This piece of code works for google chrome etc, however it not working on IE, does anyone know why or what I am doing wrong?

I have IE11, and this *has* to work on internet explorer.

**Click on dashed lined**

```js
$('.on').hide();
$('.off, .on').on('click',
function() {
 $('.off, .on').toggle()
});
```

```css
.on {
    width: 100%;
    position: relative;
}

.on:before {
    content:'';
    position: absolute;
    border-bottom: 2px solid #5092e3;
    width: 100%;
    transform: translateY(-50%);
    z-index:0;
    top:50%;
}

.off {
    width: 100%;
    position: relative;
    
}

.off:before {
    content:'';
    position: absolute;
    border-bottom: 2px dashed #666666;;
    width: 100%;
    transform: translateY(-50%);
    z-index:0;
    top:50%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="off">                        
   &ensp;&ensp;&ensp;&ensp;&ensp;&ensp;&ensp;
</div>
<div class="on">
  &ensp;&ensp;&ensp;&ensp;&ensp;&ensp;&ensp;
</div>
```

Comment: Works fine in IE on windows 10

Comment: Well is your IE running as IE8?

Comment: So I just noticed that this example works on IE in stackoverflow, but it not working on my website. Any reason for this?

Comment: I actually have IE11 ~sorry for the confusion~

Comment: works fine on IE 11 also.

Comment: Yeah, I noticed it works on my stackoverflow example but not my webpage.

Comment: If the snippet works, but it doesn't work in your site, then the problem is somewhere else, and we can't help you based on this information. Please gather relevant information you can find in the console when running your website, and try to expand the snippet until you can reproduce the problem. If you do that step by step, you will probably have located the cause of the problem quickly enough.

Answer (score -3):

i think you have to declare !DOCTYPE in order to run it on IE8.

-MultiDutch

Comment: if you have IE10+ you should use ::-ms- in your selector, find more about this on google : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::-ms-value